# Pin a build as a build step in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

Is it possible to pin a build as a custom build step in TeamCity?
I have custom script that uses the rest api to pin a build, the problem is: I would like to use this script as a build step for the current build.  For example, if a build has certain parameters, I want to pin it.  The rest api (as far as I can tell) will only let me pin builds already completed as I get an error:

```
400 Responding with error, status code: 400 (Bad Request).
Details: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Cannot pin build that is not finished.
Invalid request. Please check the request URL and data are correct.
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is it what do you mean: one of build steps of running build is to tag/pin build when certain parameter is equal to something?

Comment: @antonbormotov yes, I want to pin a build when a certain parameter is equal to something, but apparently you cant pin a build that isn't finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this [plugin](https://github.com/echocat/teamcity-buildTagsViaBuildLog-plugin) and simple shell script to `tag` build when it is running, if branch name is `develop`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "%teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS_ROOT_ID>%" | grep -q "develop"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "##teamcity[addBuildTag 'taged_build']"
fi
```

This plugin is based on [Build Script Interaction with TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-commonPropertiesCommonProperties).
I might be wrong, but it doesn't look difficult to add build `pin` handler to this plugin.
Would it meet to your requirements?

Alternatively, you could create additional build configuration, that contains only one step (api call to pin build) and trigger that build in main build configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of creating an additional build configuration and trigger that build.